# Spark dataframe pivot reshaping with extra column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

While reshaping the dataframe how to compute the sum ?

```scala
val someDF = Seq(
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","90"),
  ("user1", "physics","gravity","70"),
  ("user3", "biology","health","50"),
  ("user2", "biology","health","100"),
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","40"),
  ("user2", "physics","gravity-2","20")
).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score")

someDf.show()
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|user_id|course_id|lesson_name|score|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   90|
|  user1|  physics|    gravity|   70|
|  user3|  biology|     health|   50|
|  user2|  biology|     health|  100|
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   40|
|  user2|  physics|  gravity-2|   20|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+


val result = someDF.groupBy("user_id", "course_id").pivot("lesson_name").agg(first("score"))
result.show()
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|user_id|course_id|algebra-1|gravity|gravity-2|health|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|user3  |biology  |null     |null   |null     |50    |
|user1  |math     |90       |null   |null     |null  |
|user2  |biology  |null     |null   |null     |100   |
|user2  |physics  |null     |null   |20       |null  |
|user1  |physics  |null     |70     |null     |null  |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
```

Expected Output: Should get the sum of the all the lesson_names

```
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+----+
|user_id|course_id|algebra-1|gravity|gravity-2|health|sum |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+----+
|user3  |biology  |null     |null   |null     |50    |50  |
|user1  |math     |90       |null   |null     |null  |90  |
|user2  |biology  |null     |null   |null     |100   |100 | 
|user2  |physics  |null     |null   |20       |null  |20  | 
|user1  |physics  |null     |70     |null     |null  |70  | 
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+----+
```

But how to get the sum of all the lesson_name field score value for the particular `course_id` and `batch_id` ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some how i have achieved like this using `Window.partitionBy`, It may become useful to somebody

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val someDF = Seq(
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","90"),
  ("user1", "physics","gravity","70"),
  ("user3", "biology","health","50"),
  ("user2", "biology","health","100"),
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","40"),
  ("user2", "physics","gravity-2","20")
).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score")

  val assessmentAggDf = Window.partitionBy("user_id","course_id")
  val aggregatedDF = someDF.withColumn("total_sum_score", sum("score") over assessmentAggDf)

  val result = aggregatedDF.groupBy("user_id", "course_id","total_sum_score").pivot("lesson_name").agg(first("score"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> **@manju** again I am writing for you but only for this question
>
> **spark 2.4.3**

```
scala> result.show
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|user_id|course_id|algebra-1|gravity|gravity-2|health|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|  user3|  biology|     null|   null|     null|    50|
|  user1|     math|       90|   null|     null|  null|
|  user2|  biology|     null|   null|     null|   100|
|  user2|  physics|     null|   null|       20|  null|
|  user1|  physics|     null|     70|     null|  null|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
```

> replacing "-" to "_" from all the column name because it causes the error to access data frame column in selectExpr().

```
scala> val new_cols =  result.columns.map(x => x.replaceAll("-", "_"))
```

> for calculating the sum of null and Integer is generally not possible but we can use coalesce function to retrieve the desired output.

```
scala> result.toDF(new_cols : _*).selectExpr("*","coalesce(algebra_1, 0) +coalesce(gravity, 0)+coalesce(gravity_2, 0)+coalesce(health,0)  sum ").show
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+-----+
|user_id|course_id|algebra_1|gravity|gravity_2|health|  sum|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+-----+
|  user3|  biology|     null|   null|     null|    50| 50.0|
|  user1|     math|       90|   null|     null|  null| 90.0|
|  user2|  biology|     null|   null|     null|   100|100.0|
|  user2|  physics|     null|   null|       20|  null| 20.0|
|  user1|  physics|     null|     70|     null|  null| 70.0|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+-----+
```

read more about [coalesce](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-regular-functions.html#coalesce)
let me know if you have other query. and this accept answer if its solve your problem.Happy HAdoop

Comment: Thanks for our response but why names are hardcoded ? `"coalesce(algebra_1, 0)`? What if i have some dynamic values ? if the lable name is got changed then i have change in the code right?

Comment: Can't we do without hardcoding ?

Comment: Any other way to get the sum of those ? instead of hardcoding ? @mahesh gupta

Comment: @Manju your data frame has null values so either you can replace those value using fill.na  and use this scala function 
scala> val sumDF = result.withColumn("TOTAL", result.columns.map(c => col(c)).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2))    
 or you can use coalesce with fixed value its totally up to you.
and sumDF will dynamically calculate sum of columns.

Comment: What is this `col(c)`? Which column it will refer ? Do I need to hardcode ? And i'm sorry, Since i'm new to this spark framework.

Comment: No other way to get sum of the score without hardcoding ?

Comment: it is nothing just argument of map function. If you know you lambda function then can relate. it is for all the columns and it doesn't need to hardcode anything in place of col(c).

Comment: I am not hardcoding anything.

Comment: where you have asked the question vote up and accept.

Comment: There is just right tick down to your question just click on that.